# Is it possible to redirect to a new domain url with token stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

We are required to redirect to a third party's URL and writing previously retrieved token into localStorage. It seems after redirecting (to a new domain), the token written in localStorage is not valid anymore.

Is there any way to write to localStorage after redirection?

Comment: Which "_token_"? When are you detecting this invalidity? "_Is there any way to write to localStorage after redirection?_" No, you've to update `localStorage` before re-directing.

Comment: @Teemu The token is a prefetched string. The problem is that after redirecting to a new domain, localStorage is not visible anymore.

Comment: "_redirect to a third party's URL_" I'm confused, after you've navigated out of the page, where and when exactly are you expecting to access `localStorage` of your domain? A script on the third-party page wants to access the token?

Comment: `localStorage` is per domain. So a script running on `https://example1.com` cannot access the localStorage written by a script running on `https://example2.net` Everything else would be a huge security issue.

Comment: @Teemu The third-party system asks us to redirect, and save token in localStorge, so that they will verify the token, and allow login to their system. Yes, the steps are confusing.

Comment: As derpirscher said, a third-party can't access `localStorage` of your domain. You've to re-read their manual to make the login work, this way it definitely will never work.

Answer (score 0):

If you send this token in URL, most likely you forgot to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) it:

```js
window.location.href = 'http://example.com?token=' + encodeURIComponent(myToken)
```